# C++, How to get multiple input divided by whitespace?

Tags: c++, input, whitespace

I have a program that need to get multiple cstrings. I current get one at a time and then ask if you want to input another word. I cannot find any simple way to get just one input with words divided be whitespace. i.e. "one two three" and save the the input in an array of cstrings.

```
typedef char cstring[20]; cstring myWords[50];
```

At the moment I am trying to use getline and save the input to a cstring and then I am trying to use the string.h library to manipulate it. Is that the right approach? How else could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really **have to** use c-style strings, you could use `istream::getline`, `strtok` and `strcpy` functions:

```
typedef char cstring[20];           // are you sure that 20 chars will be enough?
cstring myWords[50];
char line[2048];                    // what's the max length of line?
std::cin.getline(line, 2048);

int i = 0;
char* nextWord = strtok(line, " \t\r\n");
while (nextWord != NULL)
{
    strcpy(myWords[i++], nextWord);
    nextWord = strtok(NULL, " \t\r\n");
}
```

But much better would be to use `std::string`, `std::getline`, `std::istringstream` and `>>` operator instead:

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> myWords;

string line;
if (getline(cin, line))
{
    istringstream is(line);
    string word;
    while (is >> word)
        myWords.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for all the information!! I knew was an easier way, and the strtok function was it.

Answer (score 2):

```
std::vector<std::string> strings;
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STRINGS && !cin.eof(); i++) {
  std::string str;
  std::cin >> str;
  if (str.size())
    strings.push_back(str);
}
```